# Div height will not grow to fit different mobile screen height

Tags: html, css

I have a website made for mobile.
The page is divided into sections where each `section` takes the whole visible page's height and width. (93% of height)

You finish editing a section, you scroll down to next section which cover a full screen again.

Each section is a `div`.

```
.section{
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100vw;
  height: 93vh;
  padding-top: 1px;

}
```

When I play with Chrome window on my computer, and drag it horizontally to see how the page fits different mobile screens, the `section` `height` stay the *same*, so when the window is wide enough the content inside a section will overflow the section to the next, it will not grow in height.

I think its because the height of my computer screen stay the same (?)
How can I check that a `section` height changes in different mobile screens heights ?

Comment: instead of 93% try `93vh`?

Comment: thanks, but no.. tried both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some changes in CSS. Go through it, it will work for you:-

```css
    .section{
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100vw;height:auto;
  min-height: 93vh;
  padding-top: 1px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just design the page for desktop and add a voewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will automatically scale the page width to fit the screen width of a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Set min-height instead of height, and you can check your application for different type of devices using chrome DevTools.
[image]
Select Toggle device toolbar from DevTools, then you can choose different type of mobiles or you can play with Responsive.